# How to use Stored Procedure Cache?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySql as my database server. I have created a stored procedure for a select query. I like to know how my database server caches my stored procedure?

If MySql save my stored procedure in cache how can I access it from PHP code?

I have referred this tutorial http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/sp-cache-sp.html but I couldn’t find any detailed description of how to use these features.

Many Thanks

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Answer (score 0):

The sp-cache-sp source file is a MySQL internal code, but all stored procedure uses query cache as defined in your my.cnf, but may be you need the `DETERMINISTIC` characteristic.

> A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters

More info: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html